# Indy's idSimpleServer reconnection

Tags: indy, delphi-xe5

I'm want to be able to re-connect to a idSimpleServer after one client connects to it and then disconnects.  The first client can connect and disconnect no problem but the next client can't.  I did a simple test procedure to demonstrate it my problem.

```
procedure Tfrmmain.btnBlockingClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Server1.BeginListen;
  Server1.Listen;
  CodeSite.Send(csmLevel2, 'Listen');
  CodeSite.Send(csmLevel2, 'Server1.IOHandler.Connected', Server1.IOHandler.Connected);
  try
    while (Server1.Connected) do
    begin
      while Server1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource() do
      begin
        CodeSite.Send(csmLevel3, 'InputBufferAsString', Server1.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString);
        Server1.IOHandler.WriteLn('0006CANPDD');
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Server1.Disconnect;
    CodeSite.Send(csmLevel4, 'Finally');
  end;
end;
```

This give the following results in my codesite log:

```
Listen
Server1.IOHandler.Connected = True
Finally
Listen
Server1.IOHandler.Connected = False
Finally
```

Notice the second connection doesn't seem to bind the IOHandler properly.  Not sure where I should be looking.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the same `TIdSimpleServer` object each time.

After the first disconnect, the same `IOHandler` is reused for the next connection, but the `IOHandler.ClosedGracefully` property remains true from the earlier connection becaue it is not being reset each time.  The `ClosedGracefully` property is reset only by the `IOHander.Open()` method, which `TIdSimpleServer` calls only when it creates a new `IOHandler`.  `Disconnect()` does not free the `IOHandler`, but it does call `IOHandler.Close()`.

The missing call to `Open()` on subsequent connections looks like a bug to me, so I have checked in a fix for it to Indy's SVN (rev 5103).

You can either upgrade to the [latest SVN release](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx), or else you will have to destroy the `TIdSimpleServer.IOHandler` (or the `TIdSimpleServer` itself) in between each connection.